# An example of a not locally bounded convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

It's well known that any convex function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is locally bounded (for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ there is an open set $U$ such that $f(U)$ is a bounded set). Are there some nice infinite-dimensional examples where this fails? Could you, for example, take an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and use its basis to construct an explicit example of a convex function that is not locally bounded?

Comment: Do you require that the function only attains real values, or is $+\infty$ an admissible value?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm looking for an example that only attains real values.

Comment: That makes explicit examples on complete spaces difficult. We have easy examples on (some) incomplete spaces - you are probably aware of how to construct such. But for (infinite-dimensional) Banach spaces, I think the task isn't (much) easier than exhibiting a discontinuous linear functional [which is a special example of the desired phenomenon].